# Unlock multiple workbooks and each workbook has their own password (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, scripting

Sorry guys i have some question about unlock multiple protected workbooks

since i have around more than 200 xlsm workbooks was protected in a folder, let say store in "C:\temp"

i have another workbook(called password.xlsm) store those 200 xlsm workbooks's password in worksheet1, i want to remove all the password of the all xlsm files by macro.

such as

```
    file  password
    A     112233
    B     225588
    C     KKK999
    ..    ...
```

and here is my code, i find some vba scripting for reference, but i am a noob

```
    Sub UnEncyptedFile()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Dim oWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim Pwcode As String

    Dim filename As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesyStemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\temp")

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        checkfilename = objFile.Name
        checkfilename = Left(checkfilename, Len(checkfilename) - 5)
           For i = 2 To LastRow
               If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = checkfilename Then
    
               Pwcode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value    
               Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name, Password:=Pwcode)
               oWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name, Password:=""
               oWorkbook.Close (True)

               End If
               Exit For
          Next i    
    Next objFile
    End Sub
```

if i check the file name is equal to the name i store in "password" this workbook in sheet1 column A
then I open the file and save the file to its original path and remove the Password:=""

i success to open the workbook(A.xlsm) but it haven't assign the password automatically so it only open the workbook but i need to input the password by hand.... and then it stops looping

could anyone help me where is the problem?

Comment: although i know there is another way can crack the excel without knowing the password, but i dun want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this although I changed the logic. Instead of looping through the folder, I am looping through the excel files stored on your master excel (`password.xlsm`) in `Column A`.

---

```
Sub Robot()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Loc As String: Loc = "C:\tempt\"
Dim pw As String, fn As String, cb As Workbook, i As Long

'Loc = Local Location
'pw = Password
'fn = File Name
'cb = Current Book

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        On Error Resume Next 'If book does not exist
            fn = Loc & ws.Range("A" & i)
            pw = ws.Range("B" & i)

            Set cb = Workbooks.Open(fn, Password:= pw)

            cb.SaveAs fn, Password:=""
            cb.Close False 'You just saved the book above, no need for TRUE
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you allowed to open a wb with a `*` at the end of the string?

Comment: it can't unlock my xlsm files, but no error exists. i think your concept is better than mine. i am wonder why there is no error but still can't work

Comment: let's me try it first, all files i store in C:\temp is xlsm (extension) such as: A.xlsm, B.xlsm, C.xlsm.......
how could i join you @urdearboy, i am a noob in this forum

Comment: `Set cb = Workbooks.Open(fn, Password:= pw)` I think

Comment: YES!!! Password:= pw, that's work perfectly, thank you guys, i learn it a lot! method and logic is so simple to understand. but i have another question, why i dun need add ".xlsm" in the variable fn, is there any different of xlsx and xlsm?